# How to identify which file failed when loading data to Athena?

Tags: boto3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I am using boto3 to create a table in Athena with JSON data in the s3 bucket. Sometimes table creation can fail because some of the files are not valid. When it fails, all I get is some general error like:

```
HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: com.facebook.presto.hive.$internal.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x80 at [Source: [B@5b028369; line: 1, column: 119]. You may need to manually clean the data at location 's3://datalake/tables/12bc2140-b20c-454b-90dd-155f49364597' before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.
```

It does not give me any information on what file caused the error.

What would be a good approach to implement the logic of finding the failing file?

I am considering creating separate tables from every file and inserting them into the final table one by one. It will allow me to understand which files fail, and I can skip them in the final table.

Do you have any other ideas on how I can do that?

Thanks